# Get content of opened Word document with Jacob

Tags: java, jacob

Is there a way to get the path or the contents of the current opened document in Word (currenct active window of MicrosofWord) using Jacob?
Or any other Java library that can do that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to a running word process like this:

```
ActiveXComponent ol = ActiveXComponent.connectToActiveInstance("Word.Application");
```

Then you can basically do everything you'd like...
Here are some [examples](http://www.land-of-kain.de/docs/jacob/)

Comment: I amable to connect to the ActiveInstance and get the ActiveDocument via
`Dispatch oDocument =ol.getProperty("ActiveDocument").toDispatch();`.
I am able to write in the document. still, I haven't manage to get its path or its text. Any tips on how I can do that? Select the full text of the document?